# How to read Telegraph's rss feed?

Tags: google-chrome, wget, rss

According to [Telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/rssfeeds/), the world news rss feeds should be this one:
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/rss

However, with Chrome I only get a blank page.

Even `wget http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/rss` throws me a file with one line in there:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://telegraph.feedsportal.com/xsl/eng/rss.xsl'?>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the Chrome browser console `ctrl + shift + j` you'll notice the following error message when the browser trys to load that page:

`Unsafe attempt to load URL http://telegraph.feedsportal.com/xsl/eng/rss.xsl from frame with URL http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/rss. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

What's happening is the RSS feed is trying to load a xsl file which is a way for website to format their RSS feeds nicely in a browser. But because telegraph have hosted their xsl file on another domain the browsers security policy won't let it load. And because it can't load chrome isn't displaying anything at all. This could be considered a bug in Chrome, if Chrome can't load the xsl it should really fall back to its default behaviour.

You can view the source code for the RSS feed to see that it is all their by loading the blank page and pressing `ctrl + u`

Comment: That's amazing. Many thanks. Any idea how I could get this also working via wget?

Comment: That's odd, give it another go as I just tested from two servers and wget returns the full xml for me.